# How to deal with back pressure in GO GRPC?

Tags: go, grpc

I have a scenario where the clients can connect to a server via GRPC and I would like to implement backpressure on it, meaning that I would like to accept many simultaneous requests 10000, but have only 50 simultaneous threads executing the requests (this is inspired in Apache Tomcat NIO interface behaviour). I also would like the communication to be asynchronous, in a reactive manner, meaning that the client send the request but does not wait on it and the server sends the response back later and the client then execute some function registered to be executed.

How can I do that in GO GRPC? Should I use streams? Is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

The GoLang API is a synchronous API, this is how GoLang usually works. You block in a while true loop until an event happens, and then you proceed to handle that event. With respect to having more simultaneous threads executing requests, we don't control that on the Client Side. On the client side at the application layer above gRPC, you can fork more Goroutines, each executing requests. The server side already forks a goroutine for each accepted connection and even stream on the connection so there is already inherent multi threading on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are no *threads* in go. Go us using goroutines.

The behavior described, is already built in to the GRC server. For example, [see this option](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/6e749384f7913be540988f62836b2418368ca570/server.go#L545).

```golang
// NumStreamWorkers returns a ServerOption that sets the number of worker
// goroutines that should be used to process incoming streams. Setting this to
// zero (default) will disable workers and spawn a new goroutine for each
// stream.
//
// # Experimental
//
// Notice: This API is EXPERIMENTAL and may be changed or removed in a
// later release.
func NumStreamWorkers(numServerWorkers uint32) ServerOption {
    // TODO: If/when this API gets stabilized (i.e. stream workers become the
    // only way streams are processed), change the behavior of the zero value to
    // a sane default. Preliminary experiments suggest that a value equal to the
    // number of CPUs available is most performant; requires thorough testing.
    return newFuncServerOption(func(o *serverOptions) {
        o.numServerWorkers = numServerWorkers
    })
}
```

The workers are at some point [initialized](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/6e749384f7913be540988f62836b2418368ca570/server.go#L585).

```golang
// initServerWorkers creates worker goroutines and channels to process incoming
// connections to reduce the time spent overall on runtime.morestack.
func (s *Server) initServerWorkers() {
    s.serverWorkerChannels = make([]chan *serverWorkerData, s.opts.numServerWorkers)
    for i := uint32(0); i < s.opts.numServerWorkers; i++ {
        s.serverWorkerChannels[i] = make(chan *serverWorkerData)
        go s.serverWorker(s.serverWorkerChannels[i])
    }
}
```

I suggest you read the server code yourself, to learn more.